# how to fetch data from twitter api using flutter without using any plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to fetch data from `Twitter` or `Facebook`...etc without using any plugins?

For example I want to:

- Authenticating the user in order to take permission to fetch his own data from the API.
- Getting user basic information (Username, number of followers and following, etc..).

I tried to search for a tutorial related to this issue but all I found using `firebase_auth` and `flutter_twitter_login` so, is it possible to do this without using the previous plugin?

I hope someone could let me know some docs for this issues :)..